# Ruby IRB output is messed up in the console on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, encoding, console, irb

I am getting very strange outputs from my IRB console. Here it is:

```
 irb(main):001:0> File.dirname(__FILE__)
 => ←[0;31m"←[0;0m←[0;36m.←[0;0m←[0;31m"←[0;0m
```

Seems like an encoding issue, right? I am not sure why this is happening. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed any irb extensions, such as wirble? Some of these add syntax colouring to the console, but they're typically *nix-oriented and thus use different codes to Windows.

Comment: Mike, yes, you were right. It was the Wirble extension, which was a dependency of another gem I had installed. I removed it and the issue was solved. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are escape codes used to set colors in a terminal program; probably most popularly to colour a prompt in an xterm or compatible terminal.  My bash prompt environment variable, for example, looks like this:

```
PS1="\[\033]2;\w\007\]\[\033[0;31m\]\u@\h \[\033[0;32m\]\!\[\033[0;31m\]> \[\033[0m\]
```

It looks like some string like that one is getting into your console and confusing it (since it's not bash and/or in an xterm-friendly terminal emulator, I guess).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm using Windows. How can I see these colors in my console? Is there an emulator you recommend? If I can't, then do you know how I can disable them because they're very ugly this way.

Comment: @picardo, I'm afraid I'm not much of a windows guy.  I use cygwin when I do have to be on a windows machine and that works fine.  You might have better luck asking on http://www.superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

As Carl and Mike pointed out, that's color information. You can have the colors actually show up if you install [ANSICON](http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/index.html). Wirble and Cucumber showed up with colored text in their output in a dos box on my Windows machine once I installed that.